# Render hash with objects belonging to instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have theses associations:

```
# Post
has_many :photos

# Photos 
belongs_to :post
```

In my show action, in the post controller, I have this:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @photos = @post.photos
  render json: {post: @post.id }
end
```

However, I'd like the json to include the photos of the post, and get something like this:

```
{
    post: 14, 
    photos {
        photo1 {
            url: /myURL/,
            id: 1
        },    
        photo1 {
            url: /myURL/,
            id: 2
        }
    }
}
```

I found many posts on how to do the opposite but not this. How should I approach this ?

Comment: I think you can use [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). Have something like has_many :photos in there and implement the photos method with your desired output.

Comment: How about using [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)?

Comment: Also, shouldn't `@photos = @post.photo` be `@photos = @post.photos`?

Comment: @Vucko my bad, was good in my controller but not in the post, thanks for the help. Isn't JBuilder making things overly complicated ? How can I tell the controller to render the .json.jbuilder file then ?

Comment: Not really, as in the gemfile (RoR 4) says "Build JSON APIs with ease". [See a basic example](https://richonrails.com/articles/getting-started-with-jbuilder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
render :json => @post, :include => [:photos => {:only => :url, :id}]
```